# How to Trigger Jenkins job from Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job where "Trigger Builds Remotely" is on and I have the Authentication Token.

[image]

**And I have these powershell script, where I want to remotely trigger the build:**

```
$headersForRequest = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headersForRequest.Add("Accept","*/*")
$headersForRequest.Add("accept-encoding","gzip, deflate")
$headersForRequest.Add("Jenkins-Crumb","crumbXXXXXXX")
$JenkinsURL = "XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:8080"
$userName = "QAA_Jenkins_API"
$Auth = "xAfsgAAXsdfdsfs"
$JobName = "Run - Powershell script"
$JobToken = "34353fgdfgd"
$FullURL = "$JenkinsURL/job/$JobName/build?token=$JobToken"


Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing $FullURL -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headersForRequest
```

**Problem:**
When I execute this Powershell script I am getting an error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : 
Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
HTTP ERROR 403
Problem accessing /job/Run%20-%20Powershell%20script/build. Reason:
    No valid crumb was included in the requestPowered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
At C:\Users\ME\Documents\TUTS\RESTApi-Calls-PShell\Jenkins API.ps1:13 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing $FullURL -Method Post -ContentType ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMeth 
   od], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodC 
   ommand
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `crumbXXXXXXX` actually a valid crumb? How did you request it?

Comment: No it's not, I am getting it via GET request to Jenkins. http://my-jenkins.com:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)

Comment: And that request returns what exactly? Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46134091/1630171) to a similar question?

Comment: It returns a crumb in text format: for example, Jenkins-Crumb:877ee39941b8ed2e6f651e2f97769bca

Comment: And given that response you're doing `$headersForRequest.Add("Jenkins-Crumb","877ee39...")`?

Comment: Yes. I just hid it in my question.

Comment: Hmm... then the problem shouldn't be the crumb. Do you get the same error when you use the code from the answer I linked to before?

Comment: Yes, same error. I am currently looking at the solution in that link.

Comment: Do you have access to the logs on the Jenkins host? What do those say?

Comment: So the solution worked from the link, but is there way to do this without providing the password? There is a User Authentication token that you can get in Jenkins User settings.

Comment: It worked $h.Add('Authorization', 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$(${API_User}):$(${Auth})"))) instead of a password I used the token I generated in the Jenkins for the user. Thanks Ansgar!

Comment: Here is the link for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131903/why-is-powershell-not-able-to-send-proper-crumb?noredirect=1&lq=1